# Preventing "Null Byte Attacks" | Java

Tags: java, security

My initial understanding on this topic is that I need to prevent some junk characters available in request to avoid these attacks.

I have decided to solve this by Pattern matching for every request parameter before using it. Most of the posts available on internet talks about Null Byte and the example given shows how file IOs are the main victims of this attack. So following are my questions

1. Is File IOs are the only thing that null byte can affect or other operations are also victims of this attack?
2. What are the char/strings/patterns I need to take care if I want to filter my request parameter to be safe for null bye attacks? I have a list and I am sure it is not complete one. **%00**, **\0**, **0x00 in hex**

The articles that I am referring to are:

http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246949/Null%20Byte%20Injection

http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=38548

http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Poison_Null_Byte

Thanks in advance

---

So to make it more clear:

First post points out the vulnerability in java that I am talking about. String **serverlogs.txt%00.db** is allowed in java but when it comes to C/C++ this is **serverlogs.txt** as in C %00 would be replace by null byte causing the string to terminate after serverlogs.txt. So we should avoid such characters. This is what I am trying to figure out which such characters I should not allow.

```
String fn = request.getParameter("fn");
if (fn.endsWith(".db"))
{
File f = new File(fn);
//read the contents of “f” file
…
}
```

Comment: (1) Why is this tagged for iOS? (2) Are you talking about null-terminated strings? Java doesn't use null termination and isn't vulnerable to trivial buffer overflow attacks like C is.

Comment: @chrylis: I may be wrong but as I understood from posts mentioned above that java uses C/C++ to do File IO operations, so ignoring these junk characters may lead to security vulnerability.

Comment: @chrylis: are you implying that we don't need to take care of null byte attacks in java. Of course if by any other way in java this null byte can be used as security threat I would be interested to know.

Comment: It would be more fruitful if person downvoting this post can also let me know the reason why they did that so that I can be sure that I am making sense or I am digging in wrong direction

Comment: Basically, no, you don't have to worry about "null byte injection" with Java. You run a risk if some underlying C library like `glibc` has a vulnerability, but that's neither a Java bug nor something you could code against if you wanted to. The only scenario where a stray null byte is a security risk is if you're manually decoding a byte stream yourself.

Comment: Agreed. I don't find the 'Java vulnerability' described in your link even slightly credible. I note that no actual proof is offered.

Comment: @Rupesh Your question's title and its use of tags ("Java" in title, a "Java" tag, and not even a "C/C++" tag) create an impression that you think the "null byte attacks" problem is Java-specific, when the problem is not. On the other hand, what you might be trying to say is that you are writing a Java program and do not want your program to be exploited in any possible way, but that is not quite obvious (at least to me at first).

Comment: @KaiChan: understood your concern, please access first post and refer to example Example#3 Java

Comment: @EJP It's a real type of vulnerability. Has been used to attack jroller.com.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried it?  I wrote this quick unit test:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
    out.write("hello!".getBytes("utf-8"));
    out.close();
    String badPath = "test.txt\0foo";
    File file = new File(badPath);
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    System.out.println(StreamUtils.copyToString(in, Charset.forName("utf-8")));
}
```

Now, if the null character broke the string, I would expect to have the contents of my file printed to the console.  Instead, I get a FileNotFoundException.  For the record, this was using Java 1.7.0_40 on Ubuntu 13.04.

**Update**

Further investigation reveals this code in `File#isInvalid`:

```
final boolean isInvalid() {
    if (status == null) {
        status = (this.path.indexOf('\u0000') < 0) ? PathStatus.CHECKED
                                                   : PathStatus.INVALID;
    }
    return status == PathStatus.INVALID;
}
```

Comment: The code in the update hasn't always been there and is not required to be present.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Indeed.  If anything, it validates the feasibility of the attack since an implementation of the JVM felt the need to explicitly guard against it.

Comment: I have tried searching for this issue on different versions of java and found this working as suggested by @Aurand. But I am sure this issue was there and it could be some with some old versions of java. I'm using Java 1.6.0_27 on Win 7 x64. Every post on internet for null byte attack mentioned above example as I highlighted in original question.

Comment: @Rupesh Note that HotSpot (the Oracle implementation) is by no means the only JVM out there.  There are several dozen others (though only a few see regular use).  There are no guarantees about how any of the others behave.

Comment: This validation has been added recently (e.g. JRE 7 u 45) http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~dxu/8003992/webrev.01/src/share/classes/java/io/File.java.udiff.html

Answer (score 3):

Not a bad question. I'm doubtful that this is a valid vulnerability on all platforms (for example, I believe Windows uses Pascal-style strings, not null-terminated strings, in its kernel), but I would not at all be surprised if some platforms and JVMs were in fact vulnerable to this kind of attack.

The key point to consider is where your strings are coming from, and what you're doing to those bytes before you interact with them as strings. **Any** bytes coming from a remote machine should always be assumed to be malicious until proven otherwise. And you should never take strings that come from over the Internet and try to turn them into paths on your local machine. Yes webservers like Apache do this, but that's also the most vulnerable code they have. The correct solution is: don't try to blacklist bad data (like null bytes), only whitelist good data.

Comment: +1 for whitelisting. In fact NUL byte injection has been used against Java in the past. Notably jroller.com by uploading a `.jsp\0.html` file. Underlying OS APIs tend to be C based.

Comment: @Daniel: +1 for recognizing the problem. Now questions arises how do I validate incoming data. I should be having some filter to work with so that I can compare incoming request parameter against it.

Comment: @Rupesh Your best bet is not allow untrusted data anywhere near filenames.

Answer (score 2):

You might also fight the issue of Null byte from the other angle!

in May 1013 Oracle fixed the problem: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8014846

**So, upgrade to Java 8 or  Java 7u40 and you are protected.**
(Yes, i tested it!), it works!

*If a link to my personal blog is not considered a spam, I'l drop it here: 
http://crocode.blogspot.ru/2015/03/java-null-byte-injections.html*

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to prevent executable code from being injected into memory after the terminating null byte of a string.

Java ain't C.

Java doesn't use terminating null byes for its strings so you don't need to protect against this.

Comment: Java libraries may be implemented by calling C functions, which may well be subject to this attack.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline a java String isn't passed to C libraries as C string, but rather a `jstring`, which is *not* null terminated. If a C library converts a jstring to a char* and carelessly ignores the possibility of there being a null in the content, isnt that outside the scope of control of the java code? The question is about nulls in java strings. I consider it drawing a long bow to worry about the possibility that it might make its way to a c library that has a possibility of having a bug.

Comment: It's the behaviour of a Java library, which just happens to derive from the underlying implementation. It happens. This weakness causes real vulnerabilities.